# Unmet dependecies with php 7 mcrypt

Tags: php, dependencies, php7

I got this error while installing php7.0-mcrypt package.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic
but it is not going to be installed
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic
but it is not going to be installed
  linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic but it is not
going to be installed
                        Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
php7.0-mcrypt : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.23-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libmcrypt4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Already tried -f install but got dpkg error code (1)

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` first?